# Что это 1е-15

Tags: java

Что это 1е-15 ?

Comment: 1 × 10^-15

Comment: Это же в школе проходят

Comment: на двойки учился, наверстываю упущенное, мистер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.000000000000001
Это почти ноль)

Comment: сударь, вы неправы, почти ноль вот 0,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 :)

Comment: @Gorets о, тут соревнование на количество нулей в записи числа?

Answer (score 12):

Это [компьютерный способ экспоненциальной записи числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BF.D1.8C.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B1_.D1.8D.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B8)